# Redirect users to home page on login

Tags: javascript, html, submit

I want to build a login page that redirects the user to the home page upon clicking the submit button, but I also want to the details of the form to be sent to the backend. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below a very basic example of what you could do with Ajax and PHP:

your html

```
<input id='user' type="text">
<button onClick="setUser()">Set User</button>
```

your javascript:

```
function setUser () {  

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('user', document.getElementById('user').value);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'user.php', true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.responseText == 1) {
            window.location.href = "/"
        }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

And your php for example (user.php)

```
if (!empty($_POST['user']) {
    echo "1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vanilla js, You can stop the default behavior of submitting and stop reloading by using

```
e.preventDefault()
```

in the onSubmit function and then post the data to the backend and redirect the page
by using

```
window.location.href = "<redirect-url>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour for HTML forms is to post a request to the backend. This can of course be overridden if desired, but in this case, the default is the behaviour you want.

There are a plethora of different programming languages that can be used for completing backend tasks as well as various frameworks and libraries. For example, you could use PHP which is a popular server side programming language. Building on top of that - you have frameworks such as CodeIgniter which takes care of much of the ‘heavy lifting’ of a language and can be faster to get up and running but at the expense of less flexibility when coding everything from the ground up.

Do you have any knowledge or preferences regarding specific backend languages at the moment?

The redirect can be handled in various ways, the most common in your scenario being posting to the intended destination (via the action attribute on your form) - in this case the url of your homepage (usually ‘/‘ relatively, which is usually preferred, or you can use the full path / domain name).

Comment: I'm mainly familiar with python and JavaScript

Comment: What I don't understand is when I add a link to the action attribute, upon submitting the form, I get a page not found error. I added some JavaScript code to do window.open("home.html") on the onclick attribute of the submit button, but I don't think that it is submitting the form details to the backend